# MongoDB document size limit

Tags: mongodb

Why can I store a BSON document larger than 16MB?

I use MongoDB *without* GridFS to store image binary data. The mongodb document state that: `The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes`. But I can store large BSON documents without problem. I check again by read back the stored documents, but no document is corrupted.
[image: Large documents without corruption]

```golang
_, err := itemdbConn.InsertOne(ctx, item)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
```

I expect mongo-go-driver return an error while insert large document, but it didn't.

**Edit:**
From the **comment** in the [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/bson/util/builder.h), I discovered that the size limit check is **not strict**:

```cpp
/* Note the limit here is rather arbitrary and is simply a standard. generally the code works
   with any object that fits in ram.
   Also note that the server has some basic checks to enforce this limit but those checks are not
   exhaustive for example need to check for size too big after
     update $push (append) operation
*/
const int BSONObjMaxUserSize = 16 * 1024 * 1024;

/*
   Sometimes we need objects slightly larger - an object in the replication local.oplog
   is slightly larger than a user object for example.
*/
const int BSONObjMaxInternalSize = BSONObjMaxUserSize + (16 * 1024);
```

It means that mongodb will return error or not randomly, depends on the operation. The comment only mentions about the **push** operation, so I don't know if it also checks the **insert** operation. I did ~1000 insert operations like this without any error ...

Comment: MongoDB version? Intuitively, I would say that compression comes into play here. I do not now of the top of my head if the 16MB limit applies to the document size by content or the size on disk. However, that could easily be found out by disabling compression. I would like do some tests to verify the behavior, is your sample data available somewhere? CSV, XML or JSON preferred.

Comment: As for your actual task, I would strongly suggest using GridFS to be on the safe side, should the size enforcement become stricter in future releases.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I just insert documents which contains an array of **Binary data** (which type is  *[]byte* in mongo-go-driver). In the image I posted above, I'm writing a web crawler, each document corresponding to a web page and the array is the media contents (images, videos, audios) in it's original format downloaded from that page. You can try easily by duplicating a document with incremental number of same image until it exceeds 16MB to observe that.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Sure, I'm checking the source code of both driver and mongodb. I'm afraid that the stored data is corrupted if the error is not returned to handle in this case. It's not about the GridFS (sure, I'll need it), but the error should be returned to handle.